# Error on my UI using SingleChildScrollView when i try to run my firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

this is my first time using community to ask about my project. First thing first, english isn't my first language and I'm a very beginner in flutter world. I'm trying to build my first mobile application using flutter and now I'm trying to connect my project to firebase (I looked at youtube tutorial). I don't know if the firebase already connect because  when I'm trying to run the application and go to registration page, there this error message.

[image: 1]

And here is my code:

```
    import 'package:dfu_check_application/common/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dfu_check_application/common/theme_helper.dart';
import 'package:dfu_check_application/pages/widgets/header_widget.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'profile_page.dart';

class RegistrationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _RegistrationPageState();
  }
}

class _RegistrationPageState extends State<RegistrationPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool checkedValue = false;
  bool checkboxValue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var nameController = TextEditingController();
    var emailController = TextEditingController();
    var passwordController = TextEditingController();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(children: [
          Container(
            height: 150,
            child: HeaderWidget(150, false, Icons.person_add_alt_1_rounded),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 50, 25, 10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                                border:
                                    Border.all(width: 5, color: Colors.white),
                                color: Colors.white,
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.black12,
                                    blurRadius: 20,
                                    offset: const Offset(5, 5),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.person,
                                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                                size: 80.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80, 80, 0, 0),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.add_circle,
                                color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                                size: 25.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: nameController,
                          decoration: ThemeHelper().textInputDecoration(
                              'Full Name', 'Enter your full name'),
                        ),
                        decoration: ThemeHelper().inputBoxDecorationShaddow(),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      Container(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: emailController,
                          decoration: ThemeHelper().textInputDecoration(
                              "E-mail address", "Enter your email"),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          validator: (val) {
                            // ignore: prefer_is_not_empty
                            if (!(val!.isEmpty) &&
                                !RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$")
                                    .hasMatch(val)) {
                              return "Enter a valid email address";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                        decoration: ThemeHelper().inputBoxDecorationShaddow(),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      Container(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          obscureText: true,
                          controller: passwordController,
                          decoration: ThemeHelper().textInputDecoration(
                              "Password*", "Enter your password"),
                          validator: (val) {
                            if (val!.isEmpty) {
                              return "Please enter your password";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                        decoration: ThemeHelper().inputBoxDecorationShaddow(),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                      FormField<bool>(
                        builder: (state) {
                          return Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Checkbox(
                                      value: checkboxValue,
                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          checkboxValue = value!;
                                          state.didChange(value);
                                        });
                                      }),
                                  Text(
                                    "I accept all terms and conditions.",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Text(
                                  state.errorText ?? '',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (!checkboxValue) {
                            return 'You need to accept terms and conditions';
                          } else {
                            return null;
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          AuthController.instance.register(
                              nameController.text.trim(),
                              emailController.text.trim(),
                              passwordController.text.trim());
                        },
                      ),
                      Container(
                        decoration: ThemeHelper().buttonBoxDecoration(context),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ThemeHelper().buttonStyle(),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 10, 40, 10),
                            child: Text(
                              "Register".toUpperCase(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => ProfilePage()),
                                  (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                      Text(
                        "Or create account using social media",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          GestureDetector(
                            child: FaIcon(
                              FontAwesomeIcons.google,
                              size: 35,
                              color: HexColor("#EC2D2F"),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    return ThemeHelper().alartDialog(
                                        "Google Account",
                                        "You tap on Google icon.",
                                        context);
                                  },
                                );
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you guys see more error on my code, please tell me because I'm very clueless about this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you are using stack as child of singlechildscrollview instead of the use column or other widget

Comment: @AliHassan hi, so I'm edit the stack and replace it with column, but it still have the same error message...

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs from `Stack` the one inside

```dart
 Column(
  children: [
    Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
              child: Stack(  // this one
```

Can be fixed by providing hight

```dart
GestureDetector(
    child: SizedBox(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, //this based on your need
  child: Stack(
```

I think you can re struct the widget and don't need to use multi-Stack.

More about [/ui/layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)  and [Unbounded height / width](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI)

Comment: thank you. actually i tried this code but it still give me an error message. and i tried to edit my code but got a new error message now

Comment: I am not sure about your new error, I’ve just tested for the error you've showed on question, And yes it is possible to have errors from other parts